# Dynamically fill form fields based on other responses before submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites, google-forms

I have a form I want to dynamically change, I have read through the documents but I cannot seem to find any definitive answer. Can I make my form remove choices from dropdown lists because they used radio button #2 for the 3rd question? Can I format text from question 1 and use it to pre-fill question 6 with the same answer (by default, needs to be changeable)?

Basically I need to use code to determine if the address was spelled with shortforms (st, rd, cres, ct) and lengthen and capitolize them (Street, Road). I don't even know if this is possible. If it is can anyone provide sample code or point me to the right help docs, it would be appreciated. If not is this doable on a webserver if some of my multiple choice options need to be read from a google spreadsheet? Could i do it through google Sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the `Form` Class of Google Apps Services?

[Class Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form)

It states:

> Forms can be accessed or created from FormApp.

For example, you can use:

```
addTextItem()
```

OR:

```
createChoice(value)
```

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createChoice%28String%29)

```
 // Open a form by ID and add a new multiple choice item.
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
 item.setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
     .setChoices([
         item.createChoice('Cats'),
         item.createChoice('Dogs')
      ])
     .showOtherOption(true);
```

You don't want to open a new form, but use the currently open one.

```
/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active form, containing a single menu item for
 * invoking checkResponses() specified below.
 */
function onOpen() {
  FormApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('Check responses', 'checkResponses')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Check current responses?

```
/**
 * Gets the list of responses and checks the average rating from the form
 * created in createForm() above.
 */
function checkResponses() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var score = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponses = responses[i].getItemResponses();
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
      if (itemResponse.getItem().getType() == FormApp.ItemType.SCALE) {
        score += itemResponse.getResponse();
      }
    }
    var average = score / responses.length;
    FormApp.getUi().alert('The score is ' + average);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apps Script HTML Service; write HTML to create a custom form; write the JavaScript code to do what you want; then add the Apps Script to the Google Site.  Or just run the Apps Script HTML Service as a website on it's own.  But this option requires you to be able to write HTML and JavaScript.  What you want to do is possible.

As far as creating the custom form, checking the user input and changing it, that can be done in Apps Script HTML Service.  Then you need to save the data somewhere.  Google Forms is made to be user friendly to people who don't have programming knowledge.

It seems like you are just looking for general information on what is possible and not possible with different products so that you can make a choice.

For reading about HTML Service, click the following link as a place to start:

[Google Documentation HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

Comment: I have HTML experience, js experience and CSS, I was really hoping for an answer like you could use getLiveResponses(e); and create a new question or something...looks like I'm going to have to do this the hard way :( Thanks for the help though.